# How can I enable sorting icons in bootstrap datatables?

Tags: jquery, css, templates, datatables, icons

I am trying to recreate the datatable from this template:

https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

It works fine, but I am missing the `up and down icons` for sorting. I do not know why they don't show up...

```js
  $(function () {
    $('#example1').DataTable()
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Data Tables</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- DataTables -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">


  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">



    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Hover Data Table</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Rendering engine</th>
                  <th>Browser</th>
                  <th>Platform(s)</th>
                  <th>Engine version</th>
                  <th>CSS grade</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 4.0
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 95+</td>
                  <td> 4</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.0
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 95+</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 5.5
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 95+</td>
                  <td>5.5</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet
                    Explorer 6
                  </td>
                  <td>Win 98+</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
                  <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Trident</td>
                  <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
                  <td>Win XP</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>1.7</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
                  <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
                  <td>1.9</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Camino 1.0</td>
                  <td>OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Camino 1.5</td>
                  <td>OSX.3+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
                  <td>1.7</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
                  <td>Win 98SE+</td>
                  <td>1.7</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.1</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.2</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.3</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.4</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.5</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.6</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.7</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
                  <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Gecko</td>
                  <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
                  <td>Gnome</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>Safari 1.2</td>
                  <td>OSX.3</td>
                  <td>125.5</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>Safari 1.3</td>
                  <td>OSX.3</td>
                  <td>312.8</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>Safari 2.0</td>
                  <td>OSX.4+</td>
                  <td>419.3</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>Safari 3.0</td>
                  <td>OSX.4+</td>
                  <td>522.1</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
                  <td>OSX.4+</td>
                  <td>420</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
                  <td>iPod</td>
                  <td>420.1</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Webkit</td>
                  <td>S60</td>
                  <td>S60</td>
                  <td>413</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 7.0</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 7.5</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 8.0</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 8.5</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 9.0</td>
                  <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 9.2</td>
                  <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera 9.5</td>
                  <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Opera for Wii</td>
                  <td>Wii</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Nokia N800</td>
                  <td>N800</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Presto</td>
                  <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
                  <td>Nintendo DS</td>
                  <td>8.5</td>
                  <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>KHTML</td>
                  <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
                  <td>KDE 3.1</td>
                  <td>3.1</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>KHTML</td>
                  <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
                  <td>KDE 3.3</td>
                  <td>3.3</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>KHTML</td>
                  <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
                  <td>KDE 3.5</td>
                  <td>3.5</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tasman</td>
                  <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
                  <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tasman</td>
                  <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
                  <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tasman</td>
                  <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
                  <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
                  <td>Embedded devices</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
                  <td>Embedded devices</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
                  <td>Embedded devices</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>Links</td>
                  <td>Text only</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>Lynx</td>
                  <td>Text only</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>IE Mobile</td>
                  <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Misc</td>
                  <td>PSP browser</td>
                  <td>PSP</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Other browsers</td>
                  <td>All others</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>U</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Rendering engine</th>
                  <th>Browser</th>
                  <th>Platform(s)</th>
                  <th>Engine version</th>
                  <th>CSS grade</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>

<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with linking to the font used to display those arrows "up & down icons".

> Access to Font at 'https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

You may download the font file from [here](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) and then include it. It should work fine after that.

**Edit:**
Instead of downloading the font file you can use Bootstrap V.3 which support glyphicon .

> Note:glyphicon isn't supported in Bootstrap V4

Add this to you app

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort">Test</div>
<br/>

<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt">Test</div>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You should probably use a free cdn https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css

Comment: @LegenJerry I tested your code, but did not work out

Comment: @Jarla I provided a link to one of your projects dependencies. A CDN is a content delivery network. Using a CDN for dependencies can greatly reduce server load and is best practice. I did not provide code for you to test.

Comment: @LegenJerry I tested your code with my example. Now the arrows look like this: https://i.imgur.com/1ZyxmFW.png

Comment: But I like that the arrow look like this: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

Comment: I think these are just normal font awesome arrows no?

Comment: Bootstrap Glyphicons. And I believe it looks different because of different versioning. You don't have to use the link I gave you. My suggestion was to use a CDN to load your dependencies.

Comment: yes I am searching for a cdn with glyphicons. But cannot find

Comment: I think I found it: https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/integration/font-awesome/dataTables.fontAwesome.css I will test it

Comment: Don't fret over it, if you are using AdminLTE for your project then just go with what they have. If you get into more of a customized project from scratch then you will probably want to load dependencies and assets from a CDN. Good luck!

Comment: No, not working... Unfortunately. I wish I could just activate glyphicon icons... Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: I finally found the missing peace:     `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`